# Regex to match IPTables src and dst mac address

Tags: regex, parsing, logging, iptables

i want to parse a iptables log using rsyslog. Everything is working except the mac address.

The logs look like this:

```
May 24 23:24:14 firewall kernel: [1199323.036594] FORWARD: IN=eth1 OUT=eth0 MAC=74:d4:35:18:3d:f0:9c:c7:a6:f1:5a:0f:08:00 SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=192.168.1.3 LEN=125 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=20570 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=50485 WINDOW=60368 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
```

"Mac=..." contains the destination mac (the first six), the source mac (next 6) and two other blocks.

I want to split it into source and destination mac. This regex matches the first mac:

```
(([0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][-:]){5}[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f])
```

But how can i match only the second mac? The last two blocks can be ignored...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubling the regular expression you have already written, but with an intervening colon does what is wanted

```
([0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][-:]){5}[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f])[-:](([0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][-:]){5}[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f])
```

From this extract the third capture group to get the second MAC address.

Capture groups are numbered by the order of their opening round brackets. Hence the first group gives the first MAC address. The second and fourth groups are the repeated hex numbers and separators.

If *only* the second MAC address should be matched then change the repeating expressions to use non-capturing brackets `(?:` and `)` and omit the first pair of brackets to give:

```
(?:[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][-:]){5}[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][-:]((?:[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][-:]){5}[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f])
```

These regular expressions tested with Notepad++ 6.3.2